# Docker COPY fails in Rider when running VS generated dockerfile

Tags: visual-studio, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, rider

I'm running into problems when trying to run a dockerfile that I created in VS2017 in Rider 2019.2. The Dockerfile works fine in VS2017, but since the company I work for also allows developers to use other IDE's we need the Dockerfile to work in Rider (for example) too.

I added a new Docker project wihtin my solution by adding Container Orchestrator Support in VS2017.

My .sln project structure is:

```
Bram.Website
> Bram.Website // contains the Dockerfile
> docker-compose // contains docker-compose.yml
```

The generated Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-1803
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwrootDock
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

The generated docker-compose.yml is:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  bram.website:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}bramwebsite
    build:
      context: .\Bram.Website
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

I changed my JetBrains build configuration according to the information in this article: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/07/18/debugging-asp-net-core-apps-local-docker-container/

My config now looks like:
[image]

My build command is:

```
docker build -t <image_tag> . && docker run -p 8000:80 --name bramwebsite <image_tag>
```

When I try to build this I get the following output:

```
Deploying 'bram-website Dockerfile: Bram.Website/Dockerfile'...
Building image...
Step 1/4 : FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-1803


 ---> d58c3fe3a54e

Step 2/4 : ARG source


 ---> Using cache

 ---> 7be7e1854e6f

Step 3/4 : WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot


 ---> Using cache

 ---> 6d53dbdcf2cd

Step 4/4 : COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .


Error: ResponseItem.ErrorDetail[code=<null>,message=COPY failed: CreateFile \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder371292226\obj\Docker\publish: The system cannot find the file specified.]
Failed to deploy 'bram-website Dockerfile: Bram.Website/Dockerfile': COPY failed: CreateFile \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder371292226\obj\Docker\publish: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I'm not sure if this is a problem with my config or if this is an issue in Rider or in the way VS generates the files. The folder at 'C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp' appears to be empty. My best guess at the moment is that Rider is having difficulties with the 'source' macro that is injected by VS2017? Any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: pass source from build-arg  like `docker build --build-arg source=src`

Comment: @PandeyAmit, thanks for the comment, but unfortunately this didn't work for me. The suggestions changes the output to:
```Error: ResponseItem.ErrorDetail[code=<null>,message=COPY failed: CreateFile \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder029146980\src: The system cannot find the file specified.]```

Comment: Did you find a problem?

Comment: No I couldn't find the issue. In the end I abandoned the idea.